# Responsive, Adaptive. A method of serving up 2 or 3 websites

Tags: html, media, tablet

I'm new to dealing with responsive website design but from what I have dabbled with its showing some great results.

I was wandering if some responsive experts can give some advice on serving alternative websites based on a mediaqueries for certain devices

Scenario A : If person a is using a desktop computer, serve this website to that device (HTML page 1)

B) If person is using a tablet, then serve mobile website. (HTML 2)
But I will go further to say, Can you use this sort of method to deal out completely different html pages? eg mobilehtmlpage.html desktop.html if that makes sense?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to check to see what the "Web User Agent" is set to. This is basically the name of the browser.

You can do this in PHP like this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Here's a list of User Agents: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

Once you check the User Agent, you'll be able to redirect the user based on this information (for example - subdomains: mobile.mysite.com and www.mysite.com). A lot of websites do this.

OR You could make a website that looks good regardless of the width of the browser, meaning you wouldn't need to redirect the user or know the user agent. This is my preferred method!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I figured plain responsiveness would be the most straight forward and best approach. But you never know... should the situation arise where you need use the Web User Agent - its an option. Thanks.